# How can I encrypt or protect a video file?

Tags: php, javascript, joomla, video-streaming

I'm trying to figure out how I could possibly encrypt or protect video files from being downloaded. I am trying to offer videos that clients need to pay for before being able to view. Basically, I can restrict it through .htaccess but that prevents me from streaming the video file as well (unless I'm doing something wrong). I can link it to youtube which does a great job in preventing downloads because of RTMPe but people can still view the actual video without a subscription at that point. The page itself will be password protected, but if someone does a simple view source, they can see the link info and then just download the file directly.

I was wondering if it's possible to change the name of a file for example video.mp4 to aQnXgId.mp4 just for the streaming purpose. I don't know if it's possible to use some sort of encryption to make this happen - maybe a php/javascript that would be able to some how match a random/alternative name to a given file or when the source code info is viewed it would bring up some sort of jargon?

Thanks!

EDIT: not sure if something like this http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php would be feasible

Comment: Please use the search function before asking question. Basically the entire Related section asks the same question. To answer your question: it's impossible. Your best bet would be a video solution supporting DRM (which pretty much leaves you with Silverlight only atm)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I ended up finding a solution that does actually do what I'm looking to do. If you would like to read up on it it's here http://www.gpeopl.es/?p=618 - it turns out you can obfuscate files using flowplayer http://flash.flowplayer.org/plugins/streaming/secure.html

Comment: if it plays on my computer, I can capture it. So all this does is make it somewhat harder to directly download the file. It doesn't prevent me from copying it.